# jQuery mobile: Appears to be reloading current page before linking off to new page

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile newb here.

When linking from a (dev) jquery mobile homepage, the current/home page seems to instantly reload/flicker before the correct page loads.

The problem seems to occur in every browser I've touched and I believe it is unrelated to the well-documented page transition flicker problem (.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }).  I have tried this, even though it didnt seem to be my exact problem in the first place...and it didnt help anything.

Thank you in advance for our help.

Comment: Erm... I'm sorry, but what's asked here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are linking off to another page from the home page if I am deciphering it correctly?  If that is the case then you need to specify that the href is external:

From the JQM docs:

> Linking without Ajax Links that point to other domains or that have
>   rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be
>   loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh
>   with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and
>   data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic
>   meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or
>   domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page
>   within your domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security
>   restrictions, the framework always opens links to external domains out
>   of the Ajax behavior.

JQM wants you to create all of the pages in one HTML file.  It then hides/shows pages as required through hrefs.  There is a way to load pages on the fly with AJAX.

If you want to revert to regular browser/server href round trips then you need to specify rel="external" and/or data-ajax="false" in the href:

```
<a href="my_external_page.php" data-ajax="false">This is my link</a>
```